# audit activity on abstract domain sockets?

Tags: linux, audit

Using the audit system (`auditd`, `auditctl`) on Linux, is it possible to log connections to Unix domain sockets on the abstract namespace (or more exactly to filter them based on the (abstract) *path*)?

For instance, I can log connections to the X server on `:0` via `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` with:

```
auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S connect -F path=/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
```

But how would I do the same with connections on the abstract namespace (`@/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`)?

Comment: @illuminÉ, you can't pass a nul byte on the command line. using `auditctl -R` on a file doesn't work either. The thing is `path` is for files on the filesystem. I suspect that there's no way like there's no way for connecting a TCP socket either, but I thought I'd ask just in case.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! Admittedly I was taking a wild guess. I thought your namespace could be made a variable and you would use the nul-byte before to make it an abstract namespace lol.

Comment: I don't suppose you ever solved this problem?  I just ran into the exact same thing :(  @StéphaneChazelas

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick look and it seems that the kernel will reject a path that doesn't start with '/', so it's not possible to pass a null there. Unless I'm looking at the wrong place, this is what enforces this:

In [kernel/audit_watch.c: audit_to_watch()](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/audit_watch.c?id=v4.2#n196):

```
if (path[0] != '/' || path[len-1] == '/' ||
    krule->listnr != AUDIT_FILTER_EXIT ||
    op != Audit_equal ||
    krule->inode_f || krule->watch || krule->tree)
        return -EINVAL;
```

It may be worth filing a bug report/request against this